# Under what circumstances is the construction "whose each" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

For context, this is based on a discussion here (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/is-the-construction-whose-each-correct)

The original question was whether the following was grammatical:

> "The set of elements **whose each** pair is ...".

The majority opinion on that question was then that this was ungrammatical (or at least unusual), however there seems to be some disagreement as to why.

So my question is this:

> Under what circumstances is the construction "whose each" valid within a sentence, and what are the governing grammatical rules for such a construction?

Comment: I'm in two minds about closevoting this as Not Constructive. It smacks to me of "appeal to a higher authority". The leading ELL answer sat uncontested for a day until I noticed it and disagreed, but I can't see the advantage of effectively reposting the same question here just because of that. Why not wait until a few more people who know their language have considered the ELL answers and cast votes/made comment/added further answers?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm sorry if that's how you see it as coming across - that really wasn't my intention. Your answer on ELL includes the sentence "I can't exactly explain why "every" is better than "each" here". I'm happy that you're right (I'm not contesting that here). I just want to know WHY you're right - and that's a discussion better suited to ELU than to ELL. I'm sorry if you feel that this is inappropriate (feel free to flag it if you do), but from my perspective this is a genuine question that is for ELU, is different to the ELL question, and isn't intended as a personal slight on you.

Comment: Okay, you've convinced me. The half of my mind that had misgivings has been overridden by the other half, which agrees with you that if there *is* a reason for what I think is a progressive shift away from *each* in favour of *every*, that's more a matter for ELU than ELL. I still don't think it's a matter of "grammatical rules" though - just "idiomatic preference".

Comment: Appealing to higher authorities than the editorial staffs at  the _Encyclopedia of British Writers, 1800 to Present_ and _New Scientist_ might be countenanced, but when one starts querying usages by _mathematicians_ ... - although I'd expect "The set of elements which are pairwise ..." (if I am extrapolating correctly from the abbreviated submission).

Comment: @Edwin: The issue is not one of possible alternative phrasings you might prefer - it's a matter of whether the cited usage *is in fact grammatical*. Or, since I personally consider that to be a "non-issue", the matter of *why many people apparently **think** it's somehow "ungrammatical"*.

Comment: Looking at a very unscientific sample in the hits of [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whose+each&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=5&share=), I would say that it is grammatical (1) in the technical writing of mathematics and (2) in the 19th century. So it may be a historical construction which is dying, but which has been preserved in mathematical writing.

Comment: @PeterShor: What do mathematicians know about grammar? They say "I *is* the square root of minus one" rather than the obviously more grammatical "I *am* the square root of minus one" :)

Comment: If anything I'd suspect mathematicians of overly logial unidiomatic barbarisms before I would of overly loose ungrammatical barbarisms. I'm likewise in half a mind to vote "unconstructive". I'd be more interested if someone could come up with a good argument that it's not grammatical (rather than merely unusual).

Comment: It is "correct" insofar as it makes sense, is unambiguous and is not taxing on the reader's comprehension. Rules of grammar may exist to validate the structure, or may need to be included as "rare".

Comment: @Matt +3 up voters: Mathematicians also say "I am ..." in addition to  "I is ..." -- they are thus >grammarians.

Comment: Why "mathematical?" "The set of elements whose each pair is ..." can refer to anything imaginable depending on context, in all cases makes perfect sense to a lay reader. It may throw a grammarian off balance, agreed, though that should not be reason to label it as incorrect.

Comment: @Kris: don't you think [these Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+set+of+elements+whose+each+pair%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=7KN&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&q=%22whose+each%22&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&ei=AgsdUfSsEvKy0AG63oGACw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42452523,d.dmQ&fp=a269a878f775b32f&biw=1144&bih=719) aren't mostly from math books.

Comment: On the other hand [these pre-1900 Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22whose+each%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_max:Dec+31_2+1900&num=10) for "whose each" are mainly the 18th century or earlier. So it looks like the expression may have gone out of use in the early 19th century, and has been reinvented in the context of mathematics.

Comment: @PeterShor: On a more serious note, I'm not sure that just because some mathematicians choose to write "The set of elements whose each pair is ..." that is magically becomes "valid" (any more than lots of Internet users choosing to say "I can haz cheezburger?" makes that sentence grammatical). The whole sentence reads badly to me, and I end up wanting to correct it to "The set of elements *whose every* pair is X". So my question is really not so much "do people ever say this?", but "is it grammatical, and if so/not, why (not)?"

Comment: @Matt: if you look at Google books, "whose each" was used extensively up to the early 18th century, it became rare (but occasionally used) for 150 years, and then toward the end of the 20th century became much more common, but only in mathematical contexts. It's usually clear what is meant. How do you decide whether it's grammatical? I agree that you probably should replace it with "whose every" unless there's a good reason not to.

Comment: @PeterShor: How to decide whether it's grammatical? - Why! Ask ELU of course! That's the whole point of this question. There's lots of esoteric grammar rules that ELU members know better than I, and the whole point of this question is to spark a discussion in the answers so someone says "Yes, it's valid because it fits the old English grammar rule X or Y" or "No, it's not because it violates grammar rule Z". To be clear: noting *that* some people write "whose each" is not what I want (because lots of people write all sorts of things). I want to know *if* it is grammatical, and if so *why*?

Comment: @Matt: I suspect that it would be hard to find a general rule explaining why *"whose every"* is grammatical while *"whose each"* is not. But that certainly seems to be what is perceived by a lot of native English speakers. Maybe somebody will give one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under exactly the conditions that you have in the question.

*Whose* is used as a relative pronoun, to introduce a clause that describes something belonging to the noun phrase it follows.

Now, there are some people do object to the adjective senses of *whose* being used of inanimate antecedents, based on the mistaken belief that it comes solely from *who*, when it comes from *whos* which comes from *hwæs* which was the genitive of both *hwa* (who) and *hwæt*(what). The objection flies in the face of much eloquent usage, and is also rarer now.

*Each* is a determiner, it refers to all of the examples of the thing that will be named, so that what is stated of them singularly applies to every one of them.

We have "each pair is". Generally, those things covered by *each* are treated as singular, unless *each* follows a plural subject, in which case they are treated as plural, with a further exception allowing (some would say not, while some would say insisting, it's here we enter into a matter of debate) if the plural subject is the pronoun *we*.

Here we do not have *each* following a plural subject, so the singular should be used, and so it is. Again, we're fine.

Putting them together we have a noun phrase "The set of elements" followed by a relative pronoun, followed by a determiner which insists upon singular use of what follows, followed by a singular use.

It is perfectly grammatical. Looking for objections to different uses of the words involved, we find that not only are there none, there aren't even questionable objections to argue against.

Now, it is relatively rare. It's common here to use *where* instead of *whose*, which ironically is a use that **does** frequently find objectors saying *where* can only refer to place, literally or figurative.

It's common to use *every* or *all*. However *each* conveys a sense of precision; it's merely a side-effect of *every* being treated plural and *each* being treated singularly leading to a sense that we are focusing on each item rather than making a more sweeping statement, and there's no real lack of precision with *every*, but that impression is worth making in technical cases like mathematics.

And for that reason, it is relatively common in such contexts.

About the only possible objection I can see to this as a whole, is that the form "[Noun]<sub>1</sub> of [Noun]<sub>2</sub>s whose each [Noun]<sub>3</sub> is..." could be ambiguous as to whether it is [Noun]<sub>1</sub> or its [Noun]<sub>2</sub>s that possesses the [Noun]<sub>3</sub>s that are being described.

However:

1. It would generally be clear from context; ambiguous forms are only a problem if they result in ambiguous reading, otherwise we can object to just about every bare expression as leaving out some information and hence being ambiguous.
2. It would lean heavily toward our interpreting it as saying that it is the [Noun]<sub>2</sub>s that have the [Noun]<sub>3</sub>s (in the example, the elements that have the pairs). Only if that reading was both incorrect, and it being incorrect was not clear from context, do we have a problem.
3. In this case we have the form "The set of [Noun]<sub>2</sub>s whose [Noun]<sub>3</sub>s..." since it's extremely common to define sets in terms of the properties of its elements, we're led very strongly to the understanding that it is elements that have pairs. All the more so since the word used for the elements is *element* (now if that was *element* in another sense, that would be ambiguous, but in a totally different way).
4. Unless we have another context to explain some special meaning of *set*, then the reading of the set having the pairs makes no meaning, and so will be instantly dismissed, leaving us with no ambiguity.

So that possible objection clearly doesn't apply here. It's also not a question of grammaticality.

In all, the form is not just grammatical, and reasonably common in the domain it is used in, but a good choice.

[Taking a look at the question on ELL, it seems that the problem was that it wasn't ambiguous enough, as what they meant was "set whose each pair of elements", which is neither of the readings I suggest are possible with the form, but that's a separate issue].

Comment: I don't think the grammaticality of *whose each pair* is affected by whether the set *elements* are pairs. Any two consecutive elements are a "pair" for the OP's purposes, and there's nothing wrong with that. It's disappointing to see that after all this time, the manifestly ***wrong*** answer to the ELL version remains by far the highest-rated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, that's not really true. The objection is not  as Jon describes, so the answer here hasn't addressed the central problem. The problem's about using two central determiners together for the same noun. Now this used to be ok  a few hundred years ago, but in modern English it's ungrammatical. Jon mentions that *whose* is a relative pronoun, and it can be but it's a relative possessive pronoun like *his* or *her*. It's nothing like *where*. *Where* would be fine because it functions like an adjunct/adverbial. So is does not represent any kind of possessive noun. However, ...

Comment: @FumbleFingers I would perhaps say that it does survive in a few archaic fossilised forms in some specific registers. For example, you can find it a lot in Indian English maths text books and  people who've read a lot of old maths texts might be familiar with it. So would be people who've read the bible as well as people who read poetry from the sixteen hundreds, like Dryden for example ;). Here's a quote from OED ...

Comment: @f ...  "*The co-occurrence rules for determiners were somewhat different from those in later modern English. Notably common was the sequence of demonstrative + possessive + noun (‘this your son’)*."  Is it acceptable in modern English outsideof the specific register of maths textbooks, more specifically geometry)? I think no. Certainly I find ""I would like to know sets of at least 3 words, whose each pair of words are false friends" ungrammatical.

Comment: @Araucaria: It's surprising how many people add an extra determiner when quoting The Godfather's [*on **this** the day of my daughter's wedding*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:List_of_misquotations#You_come_to_me.2C_on_the_day_of_my_daughter.27s_wedding...), which I agree is at the very least dated/stilted. But I've no problem with *...whose each and every move was monitored*, and I don't see any real difference between that and the usage in question here. It might present *semantic* issues, but the grammaticality itself is fine by me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, *Whose each and every move* seems absolutely fine to me too. I think it's licensed by the *every* though. We can generally use *every* like that unrestrictedly, even in modern English. Your poetry reading might be making you more generally tolerant of grammar from the Restoration!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really work well in contemporary English. *Whose* and *each* are both [determiners](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/determiner), which both expect a noun to follow. Granted, they each act like adjectives, and you can often use more than one adjective in succession (e.g., the big green coat). Even so, pairing doesn't *always* work quite so well with determiners: *these whose*, *the lots of* and *my any* are all ungrammatical.

Even if *whose each* is grammatical, it is uncommon and perhaps, a bit too archaic to use without loosing some of the intended meaning on potential audiences. However that may be, *whose every* is both grammatical and pretty common, which would work quite nicely as a concise alternative to the awkward wording of *whose each*.

You can find [examples from early modern English](http://www.google.com/search?q=whose-each&hl=en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1450,cd_max:1/1/1690&tbm=bks) or other more archaic variations of the language where *whose* acts more like *which* or *whom*, which might explain the more common use of *whose every*, where both *whose* and *every* could be defined as determiners.

*Whose each* continues to show up in publications, but it's most frequently in [math textbooks](http://www.google.com/search?q=whose-each&tbm=bks) where formal concerns dealing with precise definitions are common. Otherwise, it's rare syntactic usage which could come across as accidental. Something along the lines of *in which each*, *for which each* or *of which each* should be a pretty good fix for the case of anything current.

The more concise fix would be *whose every*, [which is much more common in English than *whose each*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whose%20each,%20whose%20every&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but it seems to work best with nouns that express motion or continuity. For example:

"Whose every" + *move, turn, jerk, jump* or *curve* would work out alright.
"Whose every" + *kink* might also work in the context of a sudden change in velocity but not so much in the sense of a discontinuity found in a Cartesian graph of an algebraic function.

*Whose every side* doesn't work as well because sides are static.
*Whose every line* works but mostly just in the context of a an actor's lines (maybe a bread line).

The issue with *every* and the idea of nouns involving motion or continuity stems from the verb which ends the example phrase, "The set of elements whose each pair *is*."

Consider what comes after the *is*: an adjective/adjective clause, a participle or a passive voice construction:

"*whose every pair is* red" doesn't work so well.(a comparative like *bigger* might work better)
 
"*whose every pair is* broken by an opposing set" sounds a little better
"*whose every pair is* hopping across the field" works alright, I suppose.

Common usage could also have something to do with the prevailing meaning of the post determiner though (or the noun that the pair of determiners modify, for that matter):

*The young man, whose last beer was one too many, is looking rather pale.*

Comment: In the case of math textbooks, it's kinda like *trying* to be formal by employing archaic forms which have fallen into disuse.

Comment: I wonder how many of the old English ones are actually using the old sentence ordering (which matches modern German sentence ordering), and the "each" is next to "whose" because the verb went to the end of the sentence, e.g. "In whose each part all tongues may dwell", which re-arranges using the modern English sentence order as "All tongues may dwell in each of it's parts"?

Comment: So why is *"whose every"* grammatical? Isn't *"every"* also a determiner?

Comment: "Whose every" does work, as in, "The philosopher, whose every move seemed to be a counterexample, proved me wrong."...Revising answer.

Comment: The other obvious place where "whose each" works is for example "The solo was performed by the mezzo-soprano, whose each and every note filled the concert hall", although in this case "each and every" appears to be an idiomatic emphasis rather than as a determiner

Comment: @Matt, I'd say in all cases "each and every" is both a determiner and an idiom used for emphasis; it's tautologous, but like many tautologous idioms, is used for emphasis.

Comment: I'll have to make another edit. It looks like the issue with *each* in place of *every* might have more to do with them being different types of quantifiers: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/4177586 (Jstor preview of *On Post-Determiner Quantifiers* by Guy Carden. See also: http://homepages.uwp.edu/canary/grammar_text/29-det-misc.html and http://flesl.net/Grammar/Grammar_Glossary/determiner.php (excercises/examples w/ explanations, much more basic).