# Why is "our today's meeting" wrong?

Tags: possessives, time, double-possessive

One of the answers to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/251548/25030) question states that *"We shall discuss it in our today's meeting"*  is grammatically correct. To me, that sentence is clearly wrong. While *in today's meeting* is fine and *in our today meeting* is OK*ish* (though at the very least clumsy), there's something about the possessive there (*our today's*) that makes it wrong for me.

I would read that sentence as *in our today's (as opposed to your today's) meeting*. Similar to *in our car's trunk* where the *our* clearly modifies *car* and not *trunk* or *car trunk*, the *our* in *our today's* seems to be modifying *today's* and not *meeting*.

So, my questions are i) is it actually grammatically wrong to say *in our today's* or is it just a question of usage? and ii) if it is indeed wrong, how can we explain its wrongness?

Comment: You figured it out: in that construction *our* modifies *today*, and you can't put an adjective before *today*. In *our car's trunk*, and *our company's meeting*, you can talk about *our car* (one you own) and *our company* (probably one you work for), but we don't say *our today*.

Comment: Actually, if you're Shakespeare, you can say *"and all our yesterdays have lighted fools the way to dusty death."* So maybe if you have a poetic license, you can say *our today*.

Comment: "our" and "today's" both qualify "meeting" and so I believe it isn't wrong (at least grammatically).

Comment: @PeterShor yes, that's what I thought, but isn't there a name for that? "Split something or other", or something?

Comment: The idiomatic way nowadays is to say "our meeting today".  But *our today's .....* used to be used.

Comment: Hi Tim - you really think that's true?  Do you have any old-days examples of it??

Comment: @Joe Blow: Yes, I do, and I do.(https://books.google.com/books?id=hwdQAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA4&dq=%22our+today%27s%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEYQ6AEwB2oVChMI0Znt6Z-FxgIVsi2MCh2Y4QBn#v=onepage&q=%22our%20today's%22&f=false)

Comment: @TimRomano that's really interesting. There are even examples as recent as last year. I don't think it's a question of today vs. yesteryear. It was no more common then than it is now. If anything, [it is becoming _more_ common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=our+today%27s&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cour%20today%20%27s%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @terdon: American English a different story (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(our+today%27s)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28our%20today%20%27s%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Tim - hmm .. every one I looked at just looked like typos, or wrong.

Comment: @Joe Blow: There are typos to be sure, but many legitimate attestations. What do you mean "wrong"?

Comment: Come on man.  You know that if I say "the more bigger" or "in last meeting" that's wrong.

Comment: @TimRomano there are too few examples to support any kind of inference about an overall trend. I'm still leaning towards all of those being cases of incompetent editors.

Comment: Very good and interesting question. I would not have noticed the error in "our today's meeting" because it is instantly understandable. It's a bit like saying "Have you got my paper?" vs "Have you got today's paper?" vs "Have you got my today's paper". The latter is perfectly comprehensible, and if it is acceptable as a dialect variant, then it is not ungrammatical. Perhaps, "non standard" would be the more correct term. Anyway, I very much like this question! :)

Comment: @terdon: We all seem to agree that *our today's meeting* is "not okay", even though I don't yet see any convincing explanation as to *why* this is so. What foxes me is it's fine for us to invite someone to *our Friday meeting* - where the genitive would be totally unacceptable to me. Perhaps it's relevant that *Friday* might be "generic" (maybe we have a "Friday meeting" every week), so you can say *Come to our Friday meeting tomorrow*, or *Come to Friday's meeting tomorrow*. But you can't say *Come to our tomorrow meeting*, with or without the genitive. Weird.

Comment: @Mari-LouA cheers :) I think the answer is in Janus's comment about [_deictics_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis), also mentioned at the end of oerkelens' excellent answer. That would suggest that it is ungrammatical, at least in my dialect. I have next to no experience of Indian English so I can't speak to that. Note that _today's paper_ might be considered as a noun phrase. I believe it is idiomatic enough that it is no longer the paper of today as such, but _today's paper_, its own thing. In any case, while I still find it jarring, probably "wrong" it bothers me less than others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ditto, have a look at Janus's comment. I think that's what it boils down to. We don't like _our Friday's meeting_ for the same reasons we dislike _the Friday's meeting_.

Comment: I upvoted [Janus's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251561/why-is-our-todays-meeting-wrong?noredirect=1#comment548215_251572), which is certainly "worth noting". But I don't have a problem with [*our last week's meeting*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22our+last+week%27s+meeting%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) and many other variations on the theme, so I'm not convinced it's a matter of "Multiple deictic qualifiers are inherently invalid".

Comment: Dammit @FumbleFingers, I thought we'd nailed it down! Yes, _our last week's meeting_ bothers me far less as well. I wouldn't go as far as saying I have _no_ problem with it but certainly less of one. You're not helping :)

Comment: I did *try* to help - by upvoting the most interesting question I've seen here for quite a while! But if I understand @Reg's position aright, he's essentially saying there is no *definitive, coherent, and consistent principle* involved here, only "arbitrary, but established" idiomatic preference. And quite frankly, I think all this guff about "Indian English" is just that. I don't believe for one moment they're spearheading some new syntactic affordance, because on average "true" IE (as opposed to "non-fluent") speakers cleave to *older*, not *newer* usages.

Comment: To put aside 'why' for the moment, "our today's meeting" and "our today meeting" are both equally grating (and badly) on my ears. And what it sounds like to me is that performance wise the speaker made a mistake in thinking 'today's meeting' and 'our meeting' at the same time and mushing them together badly (a common source of native-speaker infelicities). And to put them together in a natural felicitous manner would be 'our meeting today'. Now as to why, I have no more charact..

Comment: @FumbleFingers as an aside, InE does favour quite some usage that seems archaic in BrE and AmE, but it also, like any productive dialect, develops new usage, like _a trouser_ or _a pant_ for the, as one might argue, based on lost semantics, _trousers_ and _pants_. I only dragged it in on this one because I have only regularly heard _our today's meeting_ from InE speakers.

Comment: I'm going to repeat a previous example of mine and place it in bold. The context is the following. I am looking for my newspaper which I bought earlier  but cannot find now, I ask my partner: **Have you got my today's paper?** If "today's paper" is a noun phrase, then I can be the owner of "today's paper"  If I switch the order "Have you got my paper today?" The meaning is subtly changed, don't you think?

Comment: Actually, we clearly can use 
[our today](https://www.google.com/search?q=for+our+today+they+gave&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=for+our+today&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l2j0i22i30l3j69i60j69i61.5766j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) if only poetically.

Still Mari-Lou; Sankarane: the point isn’t that their are two possessives, or that “meeting” is qualified twice… it’s that there are two rival possessors; conflicting qualifications.

In “our meeting” the owner of the meeting is us. In “today’s meeting” the owner is today.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin yes, of course. That's what I say in the question: "our today" means "our today which is different to your today". Second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @terdon Your intention makes perfect sense and if you look back in detail, I don't see how the wording of your second paragraph supports it.

If it did, how would there be any Question?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Usually, a noun phrase in English must have exactly one determiner: you can say "I drove the car" or "I drove my car", but not "I drove car" or "I drove the my car".

Certain nouns (such as plural nouns and proper nouns) don't need determiners: "I love bees", "I love milk", "I love Paris", "I love biology". But I can't think of a case where it's ever legal to use two or more determiners for a single noun phrase. (A possible example would be "all my children", but I'm not sure "all" is acting as a determiner there.)

"Our today's meeting" is illegal because the noun phrase "meeting" has two determiners, "our" and "today's". It would also be illegal to say "the today's meeting" or "our the meeting".

Comment: A remarkably elegant answer from left field!

Comment: You’re right about _all_: it’s a predeterminer, not a determiner, and thus doesn’t violate the single-determiner restriction. For some reason, I had never realised (or happened upon) the fact that NPs marked with the Saxon genitive function as determiners before. How this came to be, I have no idea—seems like an obvious thing I should have known.

Comment: @janus and Tanner, how about _these my children_? Doesn't that have 2 determiners? Or is it a predetermined again? Great answer, by the way.

Comment: @terdon "These my children" sounds incorrect to me, unless you're saying "these, my children" (using "these" as a pronoun instead of as a determiner) or "these are my children" (leaving out the "are", as some dialects often do).

Comment: @TannerSwett I was misquoting the Bible, I guess I was looking for *Verily I say unto you, Inasmuch as ye have done it unto one of the least of **these my brethren**, ye have done it unto me*  which is from the King James version. Dang, I thought it was Shakespeare. I read it as  _these who are my children_. I take it you are suggesting that because the _who are_ is elided, it's not the same construction, is that correct?

Comment: @terdon That sounds like a plausible explanation, but I'm not actually sure.

Comment: "It would also be illegal..." *Illegal*? As in "against the law", illegal?

Comment: @Terdon, That's because in middle English it was possible to use two genitives together, in fact it was possible to use a possessive and another determiner too. So in archaic forms of English and those trying to evoke archaic forms of English you'll find such constructions that are basically ungrammatical in Modern English ...

Comment: @terdon  However, some archaic fossilized uses can be found in Indian maths exam papers, and people who read old maths textbooks such as Pete Shor and John Hana [might find it acceptable](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104004/under-what-circumstances-is-the-construction-whose-each-grammatical#comment550028_104177). So will people who read a lot of old poets from the sixteen hundreds such as such as Dryden. For example, Fumblefingers :)

Comment: @Tanner Swett: Your statement, "Our today's meeting" is illegal because the noun phrase "meeting" has two determiners." brings to mind several other examples such as: "our new neighbours", "my math teacher", "your great answer", "our afternoon break", etc. where there are two determiners modifying the same noun. There're two determiners in these examples. Why would they not be, say, "legal"?

Comment: @sankarane You could ask a main question on here: "what are the differences between determiners and adjectives?" :) or even better "What is  determiner". It is a good question. The answer to your question to Tanner Swett is that possessive words for example "Bob's" or "todays" function as determiners in the sentence, whereas *great* and *afternoon* function as modifiers. You can have many modifiers in a noun phrase "the great big brown lazy fox", but you can only have one central determiner. *"the our friend" is definitely wrong! :)

Comment: @Araucaria: Thanks for the good suggestion! There's no question about "the" and "our" next to each other. The question is about "our today's meeting". A comment on one least one of my examples, viz., "our afternoon break" could have been helpful, I guess :-) I believe a 'genitive' can also be a modifier.

Comment: @Sankarane So *today's* is possessive like *Ben's* or *our*, and it would normally function as a determiner. But afternoon is not possessive. When we see it before another noun, it is normally a modifier, not a determiner. So it has the same kind of grammatical function as an adjective such as *short* in *the short meeting*

Comment: Good! I think, "today's" is used because "today meeting" isn't acceptable, in the same way as "afternoon's". Therefore, I tend to think that both "today's" and "afternoon" (in "the afternoon break") have similar functions.

Comment: @Sankarane but we can use a posessive as a modifier too. So we can have *two man's wristwatches and three lady's wristwatches*. However, when genitives are used as possessives like this they cannot be definite (*man* in *man's wristwatch* cannot refer to a specific person). So we  cannot say *an Obama's fan*, because we know exactly who Obama is. *Today* is a deictic pronoun. We always know which day it is referring to. In a compound, we might find *a today X* but not *a today's X*. However, in the past, the language used to be different! So we could have said this a few hundred years ago!

Comment: In something like *"We are going to visit your father's old people's home"*, would the noun phrase "your father's old people's home" be considered to be illegal?

Comment: @F.E. That's another exception. In that phrase, the word "home" can be seen as having two determiners, "your father's" and "old people's", but for whatever reason, "old people's home" is treated as if it were a plain noun phrase without a determiner. "Your father's home" would not be an exception, because in that phrase, the word "home" only has one determiner, which is "your father's".

Comment: @F.E.: That is one of the exceptions discussed here: [articles with the possessive nouns in the plural](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284910/articles-with-the-possessive-nouns-in-the-plural)

Comment: I think the statement that  "'I can't think of a case where it's ever legal to use two or more determiners for a single noun phrase" overstates the rule. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Combinations_of_determiners for many exceptions.

Answer (score 48):

This seems baffling, but what is special about *today's*?

I think it comes down to this:

**We cannot use two genitives to modify a single noun.**
At least not outside Indian English.

*Today's* is a *"genitive"*.
<sub>I don't want to use the common *possessive* here, because it's hard to imagine actual possession in this case. For this answer I will use "genitive" to refer to the *form* that is used to indicate possession and that was once called *genitive*.</sub>

Looking for other examples that sound plain wrong, I noticed that it seems impossible to have two (or more) "genitives" that relate to the same noun unless it *is* possessive, and we actually intend to convey shared possession. In that case we still form a single genitive:

> John and Paul's car.

Now, if we use any other noun or adjective to modify our noun, it always *follows* the "genitive:"

> John and Paul's red car.

Note also that when we have a "genitive", we do not use an article. With non-genitive modifiers, we usually *have* to use an article:

> An old newspaper.
>   John's newspaper.
>   John's old newspaper.

Note that "old John's newspaper" is valid, but means something completely different!

In *our yesterday's meeting*, we have **two "genitives"**, namely *our* and *yesterday's*, but only one noun, *meeting*. For most speakers of English, this causes a clash, either grammatical or semantic, meaning that the sentence sounds wrong.

The same would happen with that car:

> *Our John's car.
>   *Our your car.

<sub>Note that *our John's car* can be parsed fine if we assume that the car belongs to *our John*. In that case, *our* does not modify *car*, but *John*. See also a bit further down, where I discuss *John's sister's friend*.</sub>

We have no problem with the addition of non-genitive modifiers in between a single "genitive" and the noun:

> Our great old fast red car.

As Tim Romano mentions, we can have a double genitive like this:

> John's sister's friend.

Here, *friend* is modified by *John's sister's*, acting as a single genitive. *John's* does not modify *friend*, it modifies *sister*. We can see this because we can add modifiers in between the two, and they will also modify *sister*, not friend:

> John's younger sister's friend. -> *the sister is younger*
>   John's sister's younger friend. -> *the friend is younger*

As Janus Bahs Jacquet points out, multiple genitival constructions are usually parsed as *nested*, contrary to multiple adjectival constructions, which can be parsed parallel, all referring to the same noun(phrase).

> X's Y's Z -> [X's Y]'s Z -> Z of [X's Y]
>   John's brother's wife -> *the wife of [John's brother]*
>   Alice's friend's phone number -> *the phone number of [Alice's friend]*

---

Note that I mentioned *most* speakers of English. This may become untrue quite quickly, because it seems that in the fastest-growing dialect of English, **Indian English**, this double genitive is not frowned upon, at least not always. The phrase *our today's meeting* is commonly used in Indian English, even though other dialects of English frown upon it.

The mentioned examples in the comments of *our today's specials* and *our today's speaker* will, I think, sound off to many speakers, but possibly not as much as *our today's meeting*.

It is entirely possible that a weakening sense of possession in the case of *today's* will make such double "genitives" slowly more and more acceptable for a growing group of speakers.

---

And then there is a slightly broader way to look at this, and to take in what I noticed before about the absence of articles when we have a "genitive":

As Janus Bahs Jacquet notes (and I am more quoting than paraphrasing here):

> *today(’s)* acts as a *deictic*. Deictics always add definiteness to a noun phrase, and so do possessive pronouns and determiners.
>   You can’t mark a noun phrase for definiteness twice (or mark for both definiteness and indefiniteness).
>
> That’s why neither “the/an our meeting”, “the/a today’s meeting”, nor “our today’s meeting” works: today’s makes it definite, so you can’t add another (in)definitiser.

Comment: I think you're on the right track. It has to do with how one processes the "genitive of time".

Comment: @TimRomano why just time? _John's Africa's maps_ sounds off for the same reason, _unless we assume that John owns (an) Africa!_.

Comment: Some interesting points here. Could you expand on the difference between the genitive and the possessive? I don't quite get what you mean. Also, _our John's car_ is perfectly fine in some BrE dialects, _our John_ means _my son John_, the John in our family. I can't even parse _our your car_, I realize it's an example of wrong usage but what would be the correct version?

Comment: @terdon: Modern English has only vestiges of declensions, so we're putting scare-quotes around "genitive".

Comment: @oerkelens: good point.  But I meant that if we don't process "today's" in the same way we do Africa's, it doesn't stick in the craw.  If we do, it does.

Comment: @terdon The genitive is often referred to as the possessive form, but in the case of _today's_ I feel it is difficult to grasp the idea of "today owning the meeting". The (old?) name _genitive_ does allow for describing the form without implying semantic "possession". As to _our John's car_ being correct, yes, that is a case of _John's sister's friend_. I will edit that :)

Comment: I'm a native speaker of Greek and English and the former has the genitive, so I am familiar with the concept. I had just always thought that, in English, the genitive _is_ the possessive. I think you are making a subtle distinction which is beyond my meager understanding of grammar.  Is your point that _today's weather_ is possessive but _today's speech_, for example, is not? EDIT: or is it that both `'s` and _our_ are genitives? I'd missed that.

Comment: @terdon: yes, _our_ is a possessive "genitive", and _today's_ is also a "genitive". I just tried to avoid confusion for people who would point out that _our_ means that we "owned" the meeting, whereas _today_ does not own it. Grammatically, both are genitive forms, though.

Comment: Our today's speaker.. Our today's dinner specials... are contemporary examples, I think, where the "possessiveness" of "today's" is significantly weakened by collocation.

Comment: @TimRomano I admit they sound marginally better but I still find _our today's speaker_ wrong. _Our today's specials_ is different since _today's special_ is a compound noun there. Different kettle of fish.

Comment: @TimRomano: both sound like InE to me, but indeed, the weakening of the semantic possessive may well be an explanation why they are commonly accepted. Or would you say those two phrases are common in AmE or BrE?

Comment: To phrase your point more simply, to most native English speakers, multiple genitival constructions will be inherently _nested_, rather than _parallel_ (“X’s Y’s Z” always means the [Y’s Z] that belongs to X, never the Z that belongs to X and Y). This is different from multiple adjectives, which can be either parallel or nested (i.e., “an old brick house” = nested, it’s a brick house that is old, not a house that is brick and old; but “an old, red house” = parallel, a house that is old and red).

Comment: Relative to "our speaker today", "our meeting today", "our specials today" the "our today's X" form is very rare in AmE.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _"X’s Y’s Z” always means the [Y’s Z] that belongs to X_. Don;t you mean "_"X’s Y’s Z” always means the Z that belongs to [X's Y]_? John's brother's wife is the wife of [John's brother], not the [brother's wife] that belongs to John. I think John would object.

Comment: @oerkelens Good point. Well, depends on the specific example, I’d say. But at any rate, whether they are left-branch nested ([John’s rabbit’s] foot) or right-branch nested (John’s [rabbit’s foot]), they are always _nested_, never parallel.

Comment: Hello. I am **your devil's advocate**. Don't touch **my Ben and Jerry's ice** or **my McDonald's** burger.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Three good examples. All of those, of course, have only one genitive modifying each noun phrase.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: _my [**old** devil's advocate]_, _my [**yummy** B&J's ice]_ and _my [**new** McD's burger]_. As Janus noted, every noun phrase is only modified by one genitive. But they are lovely examples. This answer is turning into a book :D

Comment: So, by convoluted reasoning, we **can** say "our today's meeting", if "our" modifies "today".  For example: our company has offices all over the world.  When it is "today" here it may be yesterday or tomorrow at some other office.  So when you refer to a meeting as "today's meeting" they may ask "which 'today'?" and you can say "our today".  Convoluted as I said.

Comment: @GEdgar: yes, indeed. It's not even as strange as you think, because it is _exactly_ why **my life's dream** is an acceptable phrase, even if _life_ is just a bit of a longer time span than _today_ :D

Comment: Oh, it’s probably worth noting also that _today(’s)_ acts as a deictic, which is why “our today’s meeting” doesn’t work. Deictics always add definiteness to a noun phrase, and so do possessive pronouns and determiners; and you can’t mark a noun phrase for definiteness twice (or mark for both definiteness and indefiniteness). That’s why neither “the/an our meeting”, “the/a today’s meeting”, nor “our today’s meeting” works: _today’s_ makes it definite, so you can’t add another (in)definitiser. (This doesn’t go when _today_ is used as a simple, non-deictic noun, as in @GEdgar’s example.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think you just put your finger on it. Oerklelens, perhaps you could include that (or a slightly uncondensed version of it) in your answer?

Comment: McDonald's is just an adjective like "yellow", that happens to have originated as a brand name (that happens to have an apostrophe in it). it has zero relation to the question at hand.

Comment: There you go. Janus cracks the jackpot. Now was that that hard.

Comment: "The phrase our today's meeting is commonly used in Indian English" where - never heard it.  What region?

Comment: @joe: so, by that token, since "today's" is just an adjective like "current" (or "upcoming", or "latest", depending on perspective), and since we can totally say "my current meeting", it is perfectly fine to say "my today's meeting". QED. I can do this all day.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: But, if it is definiteness, instead of genitiveness, then what about *the last word, the only time*? Those sound quite definite, even if they aren't. I agree with your and Oerkelens' explanation in general, but I have a feeling it is either more complicated or more arbitrary. P.S. *These our last words* is even possible in older/archaic English. http://www.bartleby.com/224/10000.html Perhaps the only difference is that we would now consider that appositive and punctuate it so...<musing> just as *King John* is an unpunctuated appositive, in a way, *my brother Orthus*.

Comment: (today's is not just an adjective.  don't use phraes like "do it all day" unless you're way on top of your game :) )  Hey oerkelens .. you know how you mention in passing "our John's car".  While I digest, I'm not sure if you meant that specific pair "our Personname's" or if you meant "our something's" more generally.  But.  Were you aware that in ScE (scottish English :) ) it's very common to talk about family member's, like that, and indeed listing them all the way back.  For example, my Mom is "our Sadie". And I'm "Our Sadie's Johnnie"....(cont..)

Comment: (cont)  And my kid is "Our Sadie's Johnnie's wee Penny" and so on (for a long boring time :) ).  So that "Our Oerk..." thing is very Scottish sounding.  I'm not totally sure how you are referring to the InE aspect, but, of course, much InE is just ScE, there's that weird thing (from saying "nite nite" to a host of forms).

Comment: @Cerberus Those are the textbook example of definite: they have a definite article, which is a determiner (as are deictics, at least to some degree) and always makes its NP definite. “These our last words” is indeed tougher to manage; I suppose I’d think of that as _these_ (determiner) modifying _our last words_ (NP), which in itself is made up of _our_ (determiner) modifying _last words_ (NP), itself made up of _last_ (adjective) modifying _words_ (head noun). A determiner modifying a NP that already has a determiner is thus possible, but has fallen out of currency.

Comment: @JoeBlow That’s not just Scottish—it’s common throughout the British Isles. And no, _McDonald’s_ isn’t an adjective—it’s a noun can be used as an adjunct. I overlooked this before, but it’s not really a genitive, either: clearly, we can all see that it’s originally the possessive of McDonald, but it acts as a simple noun, not a genitive; i.e., we can say “a McDonald’s burger”, but not “a Burger King’s burger” (because again we get the determiner marking indefiniteness, but the genitive proper noun marking definiteness).

Comment: @JoeBlow I've heard several people from Mumbai use it. Originally they came from area's as far apart as Delhi, Kerala and Gujarat. As for _our John's car_, I already put a note under it because it can be parsed in several ways.

Comment: I'm downvoting because I disagree with the bolded statement, which appears to be the main thrust of the answer. There's nothing wring with *If the sommelier intimidates you, just borrow John's Bluffer's Guide to Wine*. And if you protest that *Bluffer's Guide to Wine* is a "composite proper noun" that won't bear deconstruction in such contexts, I shall sulk!

Comment: @FumbleFingers he's not arguing against that. Note the _John's sister's friend_ example. That is just a case of _John's X_ where the X happens to contain a possessive. It is not the same as _our yesterday's paper_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _John's_ modifies _Bluffer's Guide_, just as I _do_ mention in my answer. If _John's_ and _Bluffer's_ both modify _Guide_, I shall sulk. But I'm afraid today I'm not the sulky one ;) _John's_ modifies a whole noun phrase, modifiers tend to do those kind of things.

Comment: Hi Janus, yes McDonald's (a brand name that happens to have an apostrophe in it, being used as an adjective like "yellow")  is not a genitive; has nothing to do with your argument.  I can assure you that Our Sandy's Sally's Lass is not used in Kensington.  :)  Check out Tanner's answer, you guys need to analyse it!  Finally WTF **nobody even voted for my answer, and it started all this great answer!!!**  :)  talk about no gratitude!  :)

Comment: As an Indian, I'm curious. I've never heard any competent speaker say 'Our today's meeting', and I don't remember reading it in any Indian publication. Do you have any references to support that this is valid in InE? If you don't, please consider removing it from your post. It isn't that relevent anyway. Pretty please. It's a poular question and this answer is possibly sending the wrong message out. PS- Note that Sankarane, who called this form correct in the linked question, is from Canada.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I was speaking of personal experience, hearing it from speakers I consider highly proficient. But there are online sources, for instance [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=720816744654000&id=502663486469328), _their today's meeting_ in the [Indian Express](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/politics/jk-deadlock-bjp-calls-talk-of-pdp-nc-congress-grand-alliance-betrayal-of-peoples-mandate/), ...

Comment: ... and interestingly, the Pakistani [Daily Times](http://archives.dailytimes.com.pk/islamabad/22-Feb-2011/amicable-solution-to-crisis-likely-in-today-s-meeting-fde-dg). I don't see what "wrong" message this would be sending out. InE is just another dialect of English, at par with AmE or BrE, with its own typical examples of usage. It is not "bad" that InE is different from BrE or AmE, it is natural and normal.

Comment: This usage is _not_ completely restricted to InE, by the way. As the comments show, there are quite some similar expressions that sound at least "almost" OK to other speakers. Here's an example from a Malinese Toastmasters group on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=415456321949922&id=378793572282864). Toastmasters is an English-language speaking club with, in general, a high level of proficiency.

Comment: @oerkelens: I see. I take back my objections. I guess I'm not up to speed :) Thanks for saying InE is at par with BrE and AmE, because not everyone sees it that way.

Comment: @oerkelens: Btw, among Indian dailies, I only trust [The Hindu](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.thehindu.com+%22their+today%27s+meeting%22). ([No results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site:www.thehindu.com+%22our+today%27s+meeting%22)). And I'm not on Facebook. Maybe that's why I'm not up to speed.

Comment: @TusharRaj I know, alas :) Look up _David Crystal_, he has some interesting view on InE (he once said the 19th century was the century of BrE, the 20th of AmE, and the 21st will be the century of InE). I cannot watch [this video](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/david-crystal-on-indian-english) right now, but it might be interesting.

Comment: @TusharRaj: I hear this construction rather a lot from Indian English speakers.

Comment: @oerkelens Are we to take that Indian Express article as grammatical in InE? There's a lot of things nonstandard in BrE/AmE. "The decision to meeting the Governor", etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, it because in "a [Bluffer's Guide]" the word *bluffer* has the function of modifier, not determiner. A bit like "I want to buy a [man's jumper] where the phrase *man's* doesn't refer to any particular man. It describes the type of jumper. Unless you literally are wanting to buy someone else's jumper! Incidentally, if you find *whose each* grammatical, for example if you read seventeenth century literature, you might find two determiners acceptable in OP's example. Lot's of examples in the bible, for example: "this your son" [Note this isn't: "This, your son"].

Comment: Erm how about "John's and Mary's families"?

Comment: @Araucaria: Your comments imply you think every usage must be unambiguously either grammatical or not, and that there are *absolute rules* governing every usage. Which may give some justification for quibbling over my *Bluffer's Guide* example, but I don't really see how you square that principle with the fact that usage changes over time. The fact of the matter is I'm not alone in finding *our last week's meeting* relatively acceptable, whereas *our today['s] meeting* doesn't work for me at all. (And I defy you to articulate a rule to explain *that!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's "*[our last week]'s meeting*" like "*[my sister]'s boyfriend*" but the OP's question is about "*our [yesterday's meeting]*" which is a bit like saying "*an [Obama's fan]*"

Comment: @FumbleFingers But if you could find a good sense for *our yesterday* on its own then you could probably find a context where *[our yesterday]'s X* would be OK. But it would have to be pretty contrived, though.

Comment: I like your answer, but a) Do you have any evidence for your Indian English assertion, because I can't find any supporting evidence, and b) it might help to distinguish determiners and modifiers in your post :)

Answer (score 13):

I think I have an example in which the phrase "our today's meeting"
might be uttered by a speaker of English, at least in informal conversation.

Alice and Bob are in an office in New York, USA, 
talking on the phone to Colleen, who is in an office in Perth, Australia.
Alice, Bob, and Colleen are members of a team
working on a project together, for which they have a status meeting
(by teleconference) every weekday at 7 am, New York time.
The conversation below, however, is not from the regular status meeting;
it occurs when the local time in New York is 7 pm on Tuesday,
but the local time in Perth is 7 am on Wednesday.

Alice: "Doris made a good point in today's status meeting." [She is referring to the meeting that occurred at 7 am on Tuesday, New York time, which (for Bob and Alice) is the same day as the day of this conversation.]

Colleen: "What do you mean? Today's meeting hasn't even happened yet."
[She is referring to the meeting that will occur at 7 pm on Wednesday, Perth time, which (for Colleen) is the same day as the day of this conversation.]

Alice: "Sorry, I meant *our* today's meeting, not *your* today's meeting."

I would hope this phrase would not show up in the team's final report,
however. It's extremely awkward in print.

Comment: If it did appear in print, I'd be very tempted to hyphenate "our-today's meeting" to emphasize that it's the meeting belonging to our today, not the today's meeting belonging to us.

Comment: Yes, that would work but is not really the issue I have here. If the _our_ is modifying _today's_ and not _meeting_ the problem goes away. The question here is why we can't combine _our_ and _today's_ when both are modifying _meeting_.

Comment: @terdon Could we say that this is "your my question," so that both _your_ and _my_ are modifying _question?_ If I say something about "my cousin Sally's cookies," is it possible that the cookies are both mine and Sally's but Sally is someone else's cousin, not mine? Rather than repeat what oerkelens and Tanner Swett have written, let me just defer to their explanations of how multiple genitives combine and how they don't (for most English-speaking populations).

Comment: @DavidK I don't understand what you mean. Of course we can't say _your my question_ since it is both wrong and nonsensical anyway :). My previous comment was pointing out that your example is not a case of what we're discussing here. If _our today_ is taken to mean _our, as opposed to your, today_, that's a completely different construction. The issue is about when both _our_ and _today's_ modify the same object. _My cousin Sally's cookies_ is also different since _my_  modifies _cousin_ and _Sally's_ modifies _cookies_

Comment: @terdon The point is that in "our today's meeting," at least in American English, if the phrase has any meaning at all, _our_ unambiguously modifies _today_, just as _our_ unambiguously modifies _John_ in "our John's car" (as discussed in the comments to oerkelens's answer).  Insofar as we balk at interpreting consecutive genitives this way--we do not accept that _your_ modifies _my_ in "your my question"--we consider the construction to be nonsense.

Comment: @terdon I meant for _cousin Sally_ to be a single noun phrase, as in "cousin Sally's cookies," but you interpreted _cousin_ and _Sally_ as two separate nouns in apposition in "my cousin Sally's cookies." And you can legitimately do so, so that example doesn't work. I should have cribbed "our John's car" from oerkelens in the first place.

Comment: Yes, if I were forced to parse that as English, that's how I would do it. However, the entire point of my question is _why_ is it wrong to have both _our_ and _today's_ modify meeting. I am not asking _whether_ it is wrong, really, I was fairly certain it was. The thrust of this question is on the why it is wrong. Oerkelens's answer (and its comments thread) and Tanner's address this very nicely.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the reminder that I had not yet upvoted oerkelens and Tanner Swett. Done. (Yes, their answers are better than mine.)

Comment: I liked your answer the best. :) Perhaps one can parse your example as: *"our [today's meeting]"*, where it has the meaning of: There is a meeting, and that meeting is one of ours, and that meeting is being held today--it is a [today's meeting], not your [today's meeting], but our [today's meeting]. Perhaps somewhat related could be: *"Suzy was a tomboy, but her parents bought her a girl's bike for her birthday. Her favorite uncle bought her a boy's bike, and so, now Suzy has two new bikes. But Suzy, being a tomboy, only rides her boy's bike."*

Comment: @F.E. Very nice example with Suzy's bikes. Relating it to Tanner Swett's answer, it seems that sometimes a noun in genitive form (_boy's_ in this case) is not a determiner after all, since when Suzy's uncle gave her "a boy's bike," it wasn't a bike formerly belonging to "a boy."

Comment: @F.E. you could also say: *Suzy only rides her uncle's bike.* (once you've established the context and it's clear who the real owner is. Likewise Suzy might not have her own bike and borrows her uncle's.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ah, but your example is usually parsed as: *"Suzy only rides **[her uncle's] bike**"* (with the meaning of: the bike of her uncle's), where the determiner is "her uncle's" and the nominal is "bike", where the template is "Det + X". In the Suzy example, the parsing is different: *"But Suzy, being a tomboy, only rides **her [boy's bike]**"*, where the determiner is "her" and the nominal is "boy's bike"--and within that nominal, "boy's" is an attributive modifier of the noun "bike"; in other words, *"her [boy's bike]"* is parsed similar to *"her [red bike]"*.

Comment: Usually, yes. But with the established context it would be clearer: Suzi has two bikes, one from her parents and one from her uncle i.e the "boy bike". She could conceivably call her "boy's bike" her "uncle's bike" to differentiate it from that of her "parents' ". No?

Comment: @F.E. Anyway, what think you [of this example](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251561/why-is-our-todays-meeting-wrong/251788?noredirect=1#comment549882_251561)? Would you classify it as being ungrammatical, or "clumsy-sounding"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA That might seem logical, but it wouldn't usually be interpreted that way by the hearer. It might be possible to explain to the hearer that that is what Suzy means when she says *"her uncle's bike"*--that it is the bike her uncle gave her--but it would be a non-standard way of interpreting that expression. But a "boy's bike" can also be a type of bike: the type that boy's ride with a straight bar for the saddle--compared against a girl's bike which has a low bent in that saddle bar. The genitive "boy's" happens to be an attributive modifier in "boy's bike", not a determiner.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ***Have you got my today's paper?*** <== In that context (with speakers who accept "have you got"), then, that sentence seems reasonable to me. Also, your opinion on *"Have you got my paper today?"* as having a different meaning also seems reasonable to me too.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, that is right. (But be aware that genitives have more uses than just to show possession.) And that is why I liked your answer the best. A noun phrase can have more than one genitive in it (though, a noun phrase can only have at most one determiner--where "determiner" is a function in NP structure).

Comment: @F.E. Yes, but in modern (British, at least) English a genitive NP attributive modifier must be interpreted as indefinite. We can't use definite ones, it seems. We can't have a "Liverpool's fan" for example :) But it might be different in some forms of US English it seems to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA personally, I do find it clumsy. It's not something I'd say, I would probably go for _do you have my paper_ or _do you my copy of today's paper_ or some other weaselly squirming to avoid the issue. I think the only reason it sounds OK to you is that _today's paper_ is a set phrase and you're used to hearing it, making it easy for you to parse it as a noun-phrase. Would you also accept _have you done your today's chores_?

Comment: @Araucaria we can have a _Liverpool's fan_ if that is the fan who happens to live in Liverpool as opposed to a fan _of_ Liverpool.

Comment: @terdon Sure you can have "Liverpool's fan" but you can't have "a Liverpool's fan"!

Comment: @Araucaria So, what is your favorite restaurant's today's special? My favorite restaurant's today's special for today is veal and peppers. They tell me that their tomorrow's today's special will be fish and chips. :D

Comment: @F.E. Hmmmmmmmmmm ....... Not sure!

Comment: @F.E. they also ask "how may I service you", I don't think we should be taking our cues from that industry.

Comment: @Araucaria Looking at *"their tomorrow's today's special"*, it seems to kinda offer two parses; but I've been leaning for the parse that parallels "*their* [Friday's today's special]" where the determiner function is realized by "their", instead of "*[[their Friday]'s]* today's special" where the determiner is "their Friday's". Hopefully an answer post will address this issue, of genitives that are functioning as determiners vs genitives that are functioning as attributive modifiers, and also why deictic temporal pronouns might be making things tougher. :)

Comment: @terdon  *"Do have my copy of today's paper?"* is perfectly fine, but I would use that request when I'm at the newsagent's. S/he is the person who reserves a copy of my newspaper.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with oerkelens' answer, but I am surprised no one has mentioned that the expected form, at least in British English, would normally be "our meeting today". For example, "We welcome Professor David Morrison to our meeting today." While I think most of the grammatical arguments are valid, the main reason I sense "our today's meeting" to be wrong is that a native speaker wouldn't say it: the correct idiom is "our meeting today", at least in most contexts.

Comment: But _we welcome him to our meeting today_ is ambiguous: it can be parsed as _today, we welcome him to our meeting_. The result is the same, but the meaning is (slightly) different.

Comment: This is also the preferred form in StdAmEng.

Comment: Of course it is. The issue here is why, exactly, is _our today's meeting_ wrong. We all know what the idiomatic phrase is, most of us here have a basic grasp of English :)

Comment: @philgardner: I think there's no such thing as "the expected form", as you say in your answer. There can be one backed by grammar.Your "sense'" that it's wrong is based on your personal view that "a native speaker wouldn't say it". Such statements do not provide answers.

Answer (score 3):

As an alumnus of the **Haberdashers' Aske's School**, I say with some certainty, there is no rule that you can't have two possessives before a noun.

But why is this OK and "our today's meeting" not? In this case, the possessives qualify *in a chain* - Robert Aske was a freeman of the Worshipful Company of Haberdashers, thus "Haberdashers' Aske", and the school was named for his bequest, thus {Haberdashers' Aske}'s School.

In "our today's meeting", both possessives qualify "meeting" and this is what is not OK.

---

Of course, it's trivial to make a chain of possessives. Bob's mother's dog's puppy's teeth have come through.

Comment: It doesn't; I'm using the name of the school as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: you don't own today.

The normal phrase is "our meeting today".

However, note: "All our yesterdays" is legitimate, but poetical and I can imagine a similarly flowery use of "our today" or even "our todays" but stretching that even further to have that today then possess the meeting just doesn't look like it would ever work to me.

Comment: _All our yesterdays_ has nothing to do with this. That's a plural, not a possessive. You would need to compare to _all our yesterday's thoughts_ for example.

Answer (score -1):

I'm by no means a language expert, but when I look at "our today's meeting", I feel it's wrong because of where time-qualifying words should go. In English, they always go after the verb (I went to the shop yesterday), while in my native German, and other Germanic languages (and probably other languages too) they come before the verb (I went yesterday to the shop...). I think you call that rule "time-manner-place". Here is a useful link! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time%E2%80%93manner%E2%80%93place

Comment: Sorry, but that's just wrong. _Yesterday, I went to the shop_, is perfectly correct. As is _Today it rained; yesterday it didn't._

Comment: "I went yesterday to the shop" is also entirely correct in English, just a bit odd.