# Are there nouns that undergo no change when used in the possessive (Saxon genitive)?

Tags: possessives, pronunciation-vs-spelling, attributive-nouns, saxon-genitive, possessive-s-vs-of

I’m looking for the existence of English nouns (common or proper) that
undergo no change when used in their possessive (Saxon genitive) form,
i.e. that do not take the usual *’s* appendage the way *radio’s*,
or *Paul’s* would. If there exist nouns that end with *s* or *x*, and 
for which the single possessive apostrophe *’* is widely accepted as
being optional, then that would count too.

My understanding is that every possessive noun either takes *’s*
or just *’*, but can’t confirm.

My question is specifically about the genitive form., i.e. `Bob's car`, `desk's surface`, `crucifix'`.

Since posting this question originally, I've learned a bit more about some of the taxonomy on the subject. I thought initially that the lack of apostrophe in phrases such as “boyscout club chocolate’s bitter taste” may have been a hint nouns didn't need an apostrophe in certain cases. But they're a different case.

Many have been quick to point out noun-noun compounds functioning as attributive nouns, such as in `telephone pole`, `glee club` or `mountain rock peaks` to express relative notions of "ownership"/"possession". Or that prepositions can also be introduced to express possession, e.g. "The book of Peter".

*But, I do not mean to ask about attribute nouns, nor "x of y" constructions.*

Do all nouns take the `'s` or `'` when used on their own in the genitive?

*Edit*

Similar posts:

- Discussion on whether `mens` or `womens` takes an apostrophe. Did not initially find that question because it was specific to those two instances of words. In my original post I'd mentioned whether *womens* and *childrens* without apostrophe would be considered to be spelled correctly, without suspecting I'd be stepping into a whole slew of other posts.
- Using possessive nouns in the plural. I’ve found a similar, but different question here on [possessive nouns in the plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284910/articles-with-the-possessive-nouns-in-the-plural). This kind of is what I'm looking for, but it's more about transforming nouns into attributive nouns, than nouns that don't need the apostrophe because of their nature.
- It’s been pointed out that in some countries, namely US and 
  Australia, possessive apostrophes are deprecated in [place
  names](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/is-it-common-for-place-names-to-lose-their-possessive-apostrophe). That is sort of the answer I'm looking for, but only if the last token in the chain of nouns would normally take a `'s`. 
  Are there more such cases in other fields?

I do feel at this point that the answer to my question is kind of spread on a million different questions.

Comment: Some relevant questions: [Is “mens” a valid word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112420), [Is it common for place names to lose their possessive apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2640)

Comment: Updated to add precision. Looking for Saxon genitive, precisely. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the link about place names. That's great. I'm hoping there are more cases. Perhaps some with some older germanic antiquated words, like kine and friends.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you’re asking about spelling and/or pronunciation and/or grammar? I think you might be mistaking ***attributive nouns*** in noun–noun compounds for possessive nouns, but I’m not completely certain. When you have a *child entertainer*, the word *child* is used attributively not possessively. A noun or noun phrase can only be possessive when written with an apostrophe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we say a "hotel room" and not a "hotel's room"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you sure?

Comment: @tchrist The Saxon genitive and the use of attributive nouns (and choices between them, and plural-form attributives, and the optional dropping of apostrophes from say _writers['] guilds_ and _working mens clubs_ when association rather than true possession is involved) have been done to death here. There are many overlapping questions. [St Matthew's vs St Matthew](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew/134897#134897) addresses the dropping of the apostrophe.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The are-you-sure part was whether you were sure that that was what the user was asking about.

Comment: @tchrist I'm not sure that OP knows exactly what they're asking about (as you assume, unsure about attributive noun usage? Unsure when to use this or a Saxon genitive? Unsure when to use St James's / St James' // St James? Unsure whether _dogs home_ is acceptable / preferred? Unsure whether _writers guild_ is acceptable / preferred? Unsure whether _working mens clubs_ is acceptable / preferred? Perm any 3 from 5?) But I'm almost certain it's all been covered.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be mistaking [***attributive nouns***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) in noun–noun compounds for possessive nouns with apostrophes, but I’m not completely certain.

When you have a *child entertainer*, the word *child* is used attributively not possessively. A noun or noun phrase in English is only considered possessive when it is written with an actual apostrophe, as you would have with  *my child**’s** entertainer* or a *my children**’s** entertainer*. Those are both possessives.

If you’re asking about spelling rather than pronunciation or grammar, then please see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79083/2085).

---

The only time you do not write an apostrophe for a possessive in English is when you have a personal pronoun (like *mine* and *theirs*) or the corresponding possessive determiners (like *my* and *their*).

In all other situations, you must write an actual apostrophe. This is true whether your possessive is being applied to a single word like *England’s defenders* or to an entire noun phrase like *the Queen of England’s hat*.

In your example of *“boyscout club chocolate’s bitter taste”*, the compound noun *boyscout club chocolate* is being used possessively, which you can tell because the entire set gets an apostrophe-*s* added to it. A *boy scout* is using *boy* as an ***attributive noun***, not as a possessive one. And a *boyscout club* is again using *boyscout* as  attributive noun, not as a possessive one. Finally, in *boyscout club chocolate* the two or three nouns before *chocolate* are all being used attributively not possessively. The only possessive is the apostrophe-*s* on the whole compound noun. The others are attributive.

This possessive apostrophe that we use here is merely an accepted convention for how we represent possessives in writing. Many people become confused about how to write these, but few if any are ever confused about how to say them.

The speech-rule used to create and pronounce a possessive is the same phonological rule we use to make regular plurals out of regular singulars. We do this by adding one of several phonetically determined variants of an /S/ archiphoneme: either the [s] or [z] sound, or an unstressed [əz] sound adding a new syllable, or in a few cases even no sound at all. (Some people do have a different reduced vowel there than [ə], usually [ɨ], but this is not phonemic for most of them.)

But whereas creating plurals has many historic exceptions that do not use this phonetic rule, like when we say *geese* or *mice* or *children*, pronouncing possessives has zero exceptions. We **always** pronounce a possessive using one of those various phonetically determined variants of the /S/ archiphoneme.

Which one we happen to use is not indicated by the spelling; you have to know and follow certain phonological rules. That’s why *witch’s* and *witches* and *witches’* are all written differently even though they are pronounced identically. The apostrophe has been adopted as a writing convention to tell readers which **ᴡɪᴛᴄʜ** word is meant to be a possessive.

If for whatever reason you choose to ignore the standard writing convention of using an apostrophe to mean a noun or noun phrase should be considered possessive, then you run the risk of being misunderstood or thought less of by those who think this somehow matters.

Of course in speech you have no such trouble, since the pronunciation rule is wholly regular. That and because speech has no punctuation for people to argue about. :)

Comment: "[əs] or [əz]"--In which conditions do speakers use [əs]?

Comment: @sumelic It can devoice via assimilation, as in *the witch’s spittle* as compared with something like *the witch’s broom*, where it would not.

Comment: I suppose, but if you're including such narrow allophonic variants as that, it seems inaccurate to me to say that there are "five" realizations of the affix (to me, numbering them seems to imply that this list of variants is in some way categorical and exhaustive). For example, phoneticians seem to say that /sʃ/ in English may assimilate to [ʃʃ]: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/41405.pdf.

Comment: Normally if the epenthetic shwa is inserted, its voicing carries over to the final sibilant. If anybody ever says [-əs], it's because they tend to devoice final /z/.

Comment: And there are polysyllabic nouns ending in sibilants that don't add extra syllables in the possessive. For instance, _The Joneses_ means the Jones family, and _Joneses_ in _the Joneses house_, with or without an apostrophe', is pronounced identically to the plural. Similarly with _Aristophanes plays_; nobody says /ˌɛrəs'tafənidəsəz 'plez/, though they do say /'ʤizəzəz wərdz/ for _Jesus's words_.  Mostly it's about avoiding extra unstressed syllables at the end of a word; they tend to disappear in rapid speech and that becomes a standard easily.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, you only get to apply one /S/ inflection, whether for plurals or possessives, or both, notwithstanding whoever actually says *the farmerses’ fields*.

Comment: @John I’m trying to figure out what process would cause _Aristophanes’_ to be realised as /arɪ̵ˈstɒfəniːdəsəz/. Even the Greek genitive of _Aristophanes_ does not have a /d/ (it’s a contracting s-stem, so _Ἀριστοφάνους_). As best I can tell, your hypothetical transcript would represent _Aristophanedes’ plays_, which is not a playwright I’m familiar with…

Comment: Sorry, I misspelled it. In IPA, that's fairly serious. :-)

Comment: This is a nice and informative answer.

Comment: I was indeed confusing the two cases -- genitive vs attributive nouns. And my question was somewhat unclear as a result. My question may have been considered to be a spelling question. But that post is about picking 's vs just '

Comment: Re: mine. "I like your hat's felt. But I prefer mine's." (as in I prefer the felt of my hat).  Are you certain mine absolutely can't take `'s`?

Comment: Re: "boy scouts club chocolate bars price". I was building garden path sentences, and I was hoping there existed nouns that didn't need apostrophes (or for which they were optional). In this case "a boy is scouting club chocolate that bars are pricing". vs "the price of chocolate bars from boyscout clubs". This is how this whole debacle started, and I started looking for evidence of such words. Looks like `mine` or `theirs` might be options. Thank you for a great answer! very educational.

Comment: @init_js Yes I am absolutely certain; *mine* is already possessive. If you prefer your own hat's felt to that one's, you still just say that you prefer mine. Possessive personal pronouns never take apostrophe-s to somehow make them "more" possessive. However, you could say *a friend of mine's hat* so it applies to the whole noun phrase "a friend of mine" just like with the Queen of England's hat.

Comment: I am slightly disturbed by this realization.  i.e. that possessive pronouns (or perhaps every other pronoun -- like we, that, us, them, etc.) can't take the possessive apostrophe on their own. I know it using "mine's" wouldn't make it more possessive, but it would disambiguate whether "mine" refers to "my hat" vs. "my hat's felt". I'll have to come to terms with this.